# How to get the required field indicator to show with Silverlight 4

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, requiredfieldvalidator

I've notices a number of Silverlight 4 sites use a standard orange box with an * in it to indicate that this is a required data entry field.

How is that being implemented? In the xaml file or one of the code behind pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This displays when the [Required] Data Annotation is used